# How can I send specific (SIG) signal to systemd?

Tags: systemd, kill, signals

On [systemd's manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Signals), there is a section called **Signals**, that talks about different signals and how they affect the system.

For example, `SIGRTMIN+3` reboots the system:

> **SIGRTMIN+3**
>
> Halts the machine, starts the halt.target unit. This is mostly equivalent to
>
> ```
> systemctl start halt.target  --job-mode=replace-irreversibly
> ```

and SIGRTMIN+15 immediately reboots the machine:

> **SIGRTMIN+15**
>
> ```
> Immediately reboots the machine
> ```

The man page does not supply an equivalent command. I tried using

```
systemd SIGRTMIN+15
```

but it seems wrong as I get `Excess arguments.` error.

How am I supposed to use these signals with `systemd` ?

Comment: try killing it `kill -SIGRTMIN+15 1` (only if you want to reboot the machine, of course ;-))

Comment: Notice that those signals are specifically != SIGTERM. `kill -l` in your terminal will list all the signals and their values.

Comment: Thanks alot. could you kindly explain what that 1 is at the end ? is that the exit code?

Comment: 1 is "Pid One" the process id of systemd, the init program

Comment: The `Excess arguments` is a not so much helpful error message stating that the arguments supplied to `systemd` command are incorrect.

Comment: @mosvy: is this kill command the same as this one (here)[ https://linuxize.com/post/kill-command-in-linux/] : ? becasue their says 1 means current id! (if I run this under the service will this shutdown the system or my process only?) wouldnt -1 be better?

Comment: @PauloTomé I guess thats becasue I'm not supposed to call systemd that way!

Comment: I have no time to read that whole page, but pid 1 does not mean current id. Of course you should be root if you want to send signals to init/systemd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First they are not sigterm. Next you pass a signal, not an argument. To send signals we use `kill`. See `man kill`. You have to specify the process. `systemd` will always be run as process 1, the init process.

Therefore to send `SIGRTMIN+15`, do `sudo kill -SIGRTMIN+15 1`.

However it will be better to use the command `shutdown --poweroff`, or `shutdown --reboot`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciate it